# Preprocessing Layers and KerasTuner Cooperation

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I'm having troubles making the Preprocessing layers and the Keras Tuner cooperate.

I am referring to this tutorial [Load CSV data | TensorFlow Core](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/csv#mixed_data_types) for the Preprocessing part, and to the [Getting started with KerasTuner](https://keras.io/guides/keras_tuner/getting_started/) documentation for the Keras Tuner part.

Briefly, here's the code.
He loads the data:

```
titanic = pd.read_csv("https://storage.googleapis.com/tf-datasets/titanic/train.csv")
titanic_features = titanic.copy()
titanic_labels = titanic_features.pop('survived')
```

He creates the symbolic tensors of the features in a dictionary

```
inputs = {}

for name, column in titanic_features.items():
  dtype = column.dtype
  if dtype == object:
    dtype = tf.string
  else:
    dtype = tf.float32

  inputs[name] = tf.keras.Input(shape=(1,), name=name, dtype=dtype)

inputs
```

Then he applies normalization on the numerical features:

```
numeric_inputs = {name:input for name,input in inputs.items()
                  if input.dtype==tf.float32}

x = layers.Concatenate()(list(numeric_inputs.values()))
norm = layers.Normalization()
norm.adapt(np.array(titanic[numeric_inputs.keys()]))
all_numeric_inputs = norm(x)

all_numeric_inputs
```

He creates a list

```
preprocessed_inputs = [all_numeric_inputs]
```

He one hot encodes the categorical features:

```
for name, input in inputs.items():
  if input.dtype == tf.float32:
    continue

  lookup = layers.StringLookup(vocabulary=np.unique(titanic_features[name]))
  one_hot = layers.CategoryEncoding(num_tokens=lookup.vocabulary_size())

  x = lookup(input)
  x = one_hot(x)
  preprocessed_inputs.append(x)
```

and then He concatenates it:

```
preprocessed_inputs_cat = layers.Concatenate()(preprocessed_inputs)

titanic_preprocessing = tf.keras.Model(inputs, preprocessed_inputs_cat)
```

Now what I want to do is **insert** this preprocessing part in KerasTuner. I tried this:

```
def titanic_model(units, activation):

    model_inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=28)

    dense_1 = layers.Dense(units=units, activation=activation)(model_inputs)
    dense_output = layers.Dense(1)(dense_1)
    body = tf.keras.Model(inputs = model_inputs, outputs =  dense_output)

    return body

def build_model(hp,preprocessing_head, inputs):

    units = hp.Int("units", min_value=32, max_value=512, step=32)
    activation = hp.Choice("activation", ["relu", "tanh"])

    preprocessed_inputs = preprocessing_head(inputs)
    result = titanic_model(units,
                           activation)(preprocessed_inputs)

    model = tf.keras.Model(inputs, result)

    model.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
                  optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(),
                  metrics = ['accuracy'])

    return model

titanic_model = build_model(keras_tuner.HyperParameters(),titanic_preprocessing, inputs)
```

but it gives me the following error:

> ```
> Inputs to a layer should be tensors. Got: <keras_tuner.engine.hyperparameters.HyperParameters
> object at 0x7ff52844da30>
> ```

I cannot understand if I am close to the solution, or this is not the right way to proceed.

However, the **workaround** i found was to **insert directly** in the build_model function the preprocessing layer (`titanic_preprocessing`) and the `inputs` dictionary, without passing it as an argument of the function.

Hence:

```
def titanic_model(units, activation):

    model_inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=28)

    dense_1 = layers.Dense(units=units, activation=activation)(model_inputs)
    dense_output = layers.Dense(1)(dense_1)
    body = tf.keras.Model(inputs = model_inputs, outputs =  dense_output)

    return body

def build_model(hp):

    units = hp.Int("units", min_value=32, max_value=512, step=32)
    activation = hp.Choice("activation", ["relu", "tanh"])

    preprocessed_inputs = titanic_preprocessing(inputs)
    result = titanic_model(units,
                           activation)(preprocessed_inputs)

    model = tf.keras.Model(inputs, result)

    model.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
                  optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(),
                  metrics = ['accuracy'])

    return model

titanic_model = build_model()
```

In this case it seems to work, and by setting the tuner

```
tuner = keras_tuner.RandomSearch(
    hypermodel = build_model,
    objective=keras_tuner.Objective("accuracy", direction="max"),
    max_trials = 1,
    overwrite = True,
    directory = "tuner_dir",
    project_name = "regression_tuner")
```

and searching it works:

```
tuner.search(x=titanic_features_dict, y=titanic_labels, epochs=10)
```

However, I have doubts about this solution and would appreciate feedback on this.

Thank you!